# How to test a query against a stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

```
-- =============================================

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[NST_GetCboCurrencyAfterUpdate]
@AccCurrency nvarchar(3)='',

@AccSgroup nvarchar(6)= '',

@AccInternalCie int=null

AS

BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF @AccInternalCie is not null and @AccCurrency <> '' and @AccSgroup <> ''
    Begin
    SELECT * FROM TblAccounts Where 
   AccInternalCie = @AccInternalCie and AccCurrency = @AccCurrency and AccSgroup = @AccSgroup ORDER BY AccDescription

   End 


    Else if @AccInternalCie is not null and @AccCurrency <> ''
   Begin
   SELECT * FROM TblAccounts Where 
   AccInternalCie = @AccInternalCie and AccCurrency = @AccCurrency ORDER BY AccDescription
   END

   Else if @AccInternalCie is not null and @AccSgroup <> ''
   Begin
   SELECT * FROM TblAccounts Where 
   AccInternalCie = @AccInternalCie and AccSgroup = @AccSgroup ORDER BY AccDescription
   END

    Else if @AccCurrency <> '' and @AccSgroup <> ''
   Begin
   SELECT * FROM TblAccounts Where 
   AccCurrency = @AccCurrency and AccSgroup = @AccSgroup ORDER BY AccDescription
   END
  Else if @AccSgroup <> '' 
   Begin
   SELECT * FROM TblAccounts Where 
    AccSgroup = @AccSgroup 
    Print @AccSgroup
   END
    Else if @AccCurrency <> '' 
   Begin
   SELECT * FROM TblAccounts Where 
    AccCurrency = @AccCurrency ORDER BY AccDescription
   END
     Else if @AccInternalCie is not null 
   Begin
   SELECT * FROM TblAccounts Where 
   AccInternalCie = @AccInternalCie 
   END

end
```

I have the following stored procedure , How do i test with debugging in SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT STUDIO How a particular query is being executed

```
Select * from TblAccounts where AccSGroup = '1000'
```

Say only AccSGroup is not equal to '' so

```
   Else if @AccSgroup <> ''       
    Begin
    SELECT * FROM TblAccounts 
    Where AccSgroup = @AccSgroup 
    Print @AccSgroup
   END
```

query should be executed and rest must be bypassed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you should change your stored procedure to set input parameters to null wherever they are equal to ''

so do this at the start of your procedure before any of your logic executes..

```
if @AccCurrency ='' 
BEGIN
     set @AccCurrency = null
END
if @AccSgroup ='' 
BEGIN
     set @AccSgroup = null
END
```

then change your logic to remove checks for <> '' instead check for is null

so change line like below..

```
IF @AccInternalCie is not null and @AccCurrency <> '' and @AccSgroup <> ''
```

to this..

```
IF @AccInternalCie is not null and @AccCurrency  is not null and @AccSgroup  is not null
```

Then test your stored procedure using this..

```
exec [dbo].[NST_GetCboCurrencyAfterUpdate]
@AccCurrency =null,
@AccSgroup = 'your value',
@AccInternalCie =null
```

This should get you required result!!

Change your DB layer code to check for null/blank values and pass DBNull.Value instead while setting the parameter value. 
Example

```
if(AccCurrency.Trim().Equals(string.Empty))
{
    ParameterAccCrurrency.Value = DBNull.Value;
}
else
{
    ParameterAccCrurrency.Value = AccCurrency;
}
```

Comment: If you could please help all of my permutations and combinations work except the one i have posted about it is working in sql server but not in front end asp.net

Comment: then probably there is some issue with how you are calling the SP from asp.net. can you paste that code here?

Comment: have added the DataAccessLayer Code